# Using Pandas, how do I drop the last row of each group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'one'], 'B': range(6)})
grouped = df.groupby('A')
print grouped.head()

             A  B
A                
one   0    one  0
      1    one  1
      5    one  5
three 3  three  3
      4  three  4
two   2    two  2
```

I can easily select the last rows of each group by doing:

```
print(grouped.agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]))

      B
A       
one    5
three  4
two    2
```

How can I drop the last row of each group instead? The result would be:

```
       A  B
0    one  0
1    one  1
3  three  3
```

I have tried filtering, but it does not seem to do anything:

```
print grouped.filter(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])

       A  B
0    one  0
1    one  1
5    one  5
3  three  3
4  three  4
2    two  2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

You might find it faster to use [cumcount](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items):

```
In [11]: df[grouped.cumcount(ascending=False) > 0]
Out[11]: 
       A  B
0    one  0
1    one  1
3  three  3
```

Comment: Nice.  And should be at least several times faster.

Comment: @DSM I did wonder if this should be available as head(-2) or tail(-2)... probably not.

Comment: timeits on a 40m record df:`% timeit temp=dfd.groupby('bucket', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1])`
1 loops, best of 3: 17.1 s per loop

Comment: % timeit `temp=dfd.groupby('bucket', as_index=False).cumcount(ascending=False)`
1 loops, best of 3: 4.24 s per loop

Answer (score 12):

How about:

```
>>> df.groupby("A", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1])
       A  B
0    one  0
1    one  1
3  three  3

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: In pandas 0.12.0, the index still comes out as 'A' (with that label) for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```py
df.drop(df.groupby('A').tail(1).index, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df[df.duplicated('A', keep='last')]
```

Output:

```
       A  B
0    one  0
1    one  1
3  three  3
```