# How to delete the last line of a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to handle the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   'sum':[1,1,1,2,3,1,4,4,4],
                   'flg':[1,np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'year':[2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]})

df['diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['sum'].apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[-1])
```

[image]

The 'diff' is the difference from the 'sum' of the final year of each ID.

So, I tried the following code to remove the final year row used for comparison.

```
comp = df.groupby('ID').last().reset_index()
col = list(df.columns)
fin =pd.merge(df, comp, on=col, how='outer', indicator=True).query(f'_merge != "both"')
```

But here is where the problem arises.

The contents of 'comp' are as follows.

[image]

**The 'comp' I originally wanted to get is below.**

```
ID sum flg year diff
1   1  Nan 2019    0
2   3  Nan 2020    0
3   4  Nan 2021    0
```

**Why is the Nan in 'flg' being complemented to 1 by itself?**
Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pandas, how do I drop the last row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670941/using-pandas-how-do-i-drop-the-last-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use `head(-1)`:

```
g = df.groupby('ID')

out = g.head(-1).assign(diff=g['sum'].apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[-1]))
```

output:

```
   ID  sum  flg  year  diff
0   1    1  1.0  2018     0
2   2    1  1.0  2018    -2
3   2    2  NaN  2019    -1
5   3    1  1.0  2018    -3
6   3    4  1.0  2019     0
7   3    4  NaN  2020     0
```

Variant:

```
g = df.groupby('ID')

out = g.head(-1).assign(diff=lambda d: d['sum'].sub(g['sum'].transform('last')))
```

Comment: I tried to run it as shown, but all but the 'diff' columns are Nan.
Is there a problem?

Comment: Can you check again with the provided example?

Comment: Resolved successfully. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For a fix to your problem see other answers. Concerning your question "Why is the Nan in 'flg' being complemented to 1 by itself?":

`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last` does *not* just pick the last row in each group, as one might assume, but finds the last non-nan value in each individual column within the group. In the Pandas [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e8093ba372f9adfe79439d90fe74b0b5b6dea9d6/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L2257-L2280) this is evident from the function

```
def last(x: Series):
    """Helper function for last item that isn't NA."""
    arr = x.array[notna(x.array)]
    if not len(arr):
        return np.nan
    return arr[-1]
```

which is applied to each column. I think the Pandas API reference could be a bit more explicit there (rather than "Compute last of group values.").

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `duplicated`:

```
df['diff'] = df['sum'] - df.groupby('ID')['sum'].transform('last')
df = df[df.duplicated('ID', keep='last')]
```

Output:

```
   ID  sum  flg  year  diff
0   1    1  1.0  2018     0
2   2    1  1.0  2018    -2
3   2    2  NaN  2019    -1
5   3    1  1.0  2018    -3
6   3    4  1.0  2019     0
7   3    4  NaN  2020     0
```

Comment: It's a nice way, but using `groupby` + `duplicated` is more or less equivalent to `groupby` twice.

Answer (score 1):

replace last with tail(1) and drop the added index column:

```
comp = df.groupby('ID').tail(1).reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   ID  sum  flg  year  diff
0   1    1  NaN  2019     0
1   2    3  NaN  2020     0
2   3    4  NaN  2021     0
```